# openjdk8 source miss java_lang_String.h file

Tags: java

I cloned openjdk8u source with mercurial, but found it is missing some files such as `java_lang_String.h`. Where do I get the files?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not "missing".  It is not included in the OpenJDK source tree *by design*.  See

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-1221207

If you need this file, you can generate it using the JNI header generator.

- With Java 8 and earlier, use the `javah` tool.
- With Java 9 and later, you should use `javac -h`; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javah.htm#JSWOR687

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried `javah` and generated a header file, but there are so many header files needed to be generated, can I only generate it manually? Is there a script to complete it automatically?

Comment: What build system are you using?

Comment: My system is centos7.

Comment: I had read file `README-builds.html`, was it used to compile the source?  Can it generate header files?

Comment: If you follow the build instructions, then any JNI headers needed  by the JDK build itself should be generated. If you need headers for another project, then the build script **for that project** should build any JNI headers that it needs.  Depending on the build system that you use for the project.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. Then I try to build it followed the build instructions, but occurred some error, do you know why it happened?

Comment: This is my error of duration building: 

gmake[2]: *** [/root/repositories/net/openjdk/openjdk8u/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/jdk/classes/_the.BUILD_JDK_batch] Error 137
gmake[1]: *** [classes-only] Error 2
make: *** [jdk-only] Error 2

Comment: That's not the real error message.   That's just saying that something failed earlier.

Comment: You mean I could don`t take care of this message? Yes, I found all class files copiled but no header files and no java javac and so on, you know why?

Comment: No I don't. What I mean is you should look through all of the previous build output to find out why the build failed.  The build instructions warn that running a JVM build requires expertise, and that includes expertise in how to diagnose build failures.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely. I will read the build instruction again and try to build it.